# lightningStylesheets=true doesn't render User lookup links

Tags: lightning-experience

We recently added lightningStylesheets=true to our VF pages and noticed that apex:inputField doesn't render correctly in LEX when the field is a lookup to a user. It renders as two inputs - one to select the user type, and the other a lookup field. Clicking on the lookup icon invokes a search modal in classic, but in LEX it does nothing.

Does anyone know of an easy fix, or the ETA for a Salesforce fix?